# String comparison (not equals) syntax for SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am trying to do a string comparison, between a string that will be read from a config file and a string that I mention. Is the below correct?

```
%if &strategy ne 'ABC' %then %do;
if ctry eq 'CAN' or ctry eq 'US' then maxpos = 0;
%end;
%else %do;
if ctry eq 'US' then maxpos = 0;
```

strategy is the parameter that will be read from a config file in which I will specify strategy = ABC

1. does ABC have to be specified in quotes?
2. Is the use of ne (not equal) correct?

Comment: Show an example of the config file and how it is read in.  Sounds like every 'item' in the config file might have it's value stored in a like named macro variable.  When **you** control the config file generation, sometimes it is easier to by-pass the read in phase and make the config file a series of %let statements -- in such a case just %include the config file.  When you are given a config file from some other person or process, it might be csv or xml and you would have to read it in.

Answer (score 2):

Macro language doesn't naturally use quotes for the most part (in comparisons like this, they're treated more or less as normal characters, not as string-enclosures), so it depends on whether `&strategy` contains the quote character or not.

```
%let strategy=ABC;
%if &strategy = 'ABC' %then %put equals; %else %put not equals;
...
not equals
```

but

```
%let strategy='ABC';
%if &strategy = 'ABC' %then %put equals; %else %put not equals;
...
equals
```

You would generally compare `%if &strategy eq ABC` in most cases.

`ne` and `eq` are fine, or you can use `=` and `^=`, up to you - I prefer `ne`.

Comment: Note: I'm assuming you're putting the `&strategy` parameter into a macro variable.  You don't have to - if you're reading from a text file you could've put it into a data step variable, in which case this doesn't apply.

Comment: Thanks! so, the strategy param is being read from a txt file, where I mention : strategy = ABC. How should the not equals be in that case?

Comment: You'd need to provide the code (in the question please) for how you're reading it in; you could read it into a macro variable or into a data step variable.  Either way macro language and data step language mostly use the same operators, just that macro language doesn't use quotation marks.